# Having problems with accessing struct

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I think i may be losing it but can anyone double check my sanity? This is the only code i wrote in a new file to see my project file is not messed up.

[image]

Error: This declaration has no storage class or type specifier

Error: Expected a ";"

Comment: You can't have expressions (such as `g.a = 1;`), outside of functions.

Comment: Also remove `typedef` in front and the `Game` after the closing brace of the struct declaration.

Comment: @juanchopanza Wait, why not?

Comment: The rules of the language.

Comment: What sort of smelly c++ is that?

Comment: problems with access are usually something like "unknown variable 'a' of class 'Game'", yours is clearly "syntax error"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a global level you can only have declarations and definitions, not statements (like `g.a = 1;` is) or expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Have some function to have the executable statement, for example,

```
Game Init() {
    Game result;
    result.a = 1; // g is global
    return result;
}

Game g = Init();
```

Even better to have a class called Game and have the constructor to do the initialization.

```
class Game {
  int a;
  public:  
  Game(int a_):a(a_){}
};

Game g(1);
```

Comment: Ok, lets say i am using C and want the declaration public. Is there a way i can achieve it? I know it may sound silly as you would say not use struct at all... Also, keep in mind i don't know the data type of a.

Comment: In C, everything is public within a struct, no notion of private data members, however, to initialize you need to know the datatype, Game g = {1}; would do too

Answer (score 0):

Also why not use by static initialization?

```
Game g = { 1 };
```